# Rsync - How to ignore for one of same name folder

Tags: linux, shell, rsync

I have two folders

```
frontend/static/
static/
```

I want to rsync first folder but want to ignore second folder

```
rsync -av --delete --exclude-from 'rsync_exclude.txt'
```

I write in `rsyng_exclude.txt`

`static`

igonore both

or

`./static/`

ignore neither.

Is there any method to ignore only `static/` and rsync `frontend/static/`

Comment: Using `/static` instead of `./static/` is going to solve the issue?

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, it solves.... you save my time so much